# is there any role.edit toggle function of some sort? I am making a command that's supposed to toggle between permissions but cant seem to do it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a command where i can toggle between permission states, either its enabled or not. I was wondering if there is some great method to do this.
I want to be able to just write ;editrole [role] [permission] and it should change its state from disabled to enabled or opposite.

[image: This is how i want it to look ish.]

I probably have a lot of hardcoding as well, so please come with suggestions for reducing my code as well.

Thanks in advance.

```
const {
    RichEmbed
} = require("discord.js")
const {
    redlight
} = require("../../colours.json")
const {
    stripIndents
} = require("common-tags");
module.exports = {
    config: {
        name: "editrole",
        description: "You're able to change every permission.",
        usage: "<Rolename>",
        category: "moderation",
        accessableby: "Moderators",
        aliases: ["er", "roleedit"]
    },
    run: async (bot, message, args) => {
        let permAdministrator;
        let viewAudit;
        let manageServer;
        let manageRoles;
        let manageChannels;
        let kickMembers;
        let banMembers;
        let changeNickname;
        let sendMessages;
        let manageMessages;
        let Connect;
        let Speak;
        let muteMembers;
        let defeanMembers;
        let moveMembers;
        let switchCase;
        if(args[1])
        {
            switchCase = args[1].toLowerCase();
        }
        if (!message.member.hasPermission(["MANAGE_ROLES"])) return message.channel.send("You dont have permission to perform this command!")
        if(!args[0]) return message.channel.send("Please state a name for the role you would like to edit.");
        let role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === args[0]);
        if(role === null) return message.channel.send(`**${args[0]}** is not a valid role, did you spell it correctly?`);
        if(role.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')){permAdministrator = true;} else {permAdministrator = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('VIEW_AUDIT_LOG')){viewAudit = true;} else {viewAudit = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD')){manageServer = true;} else {manageServer = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('MANAGE_ROLES')){manageRoles = true;} else {manageRoles = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('MANAGE_CHANNELS')){manageChannels = true;} else {manageChannels = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('KICK_MEMBERS')){kickMembers = true;} else {kickMembers = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')){banMembers = true;} else {banMembers = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('CHANGE_NICKNAME')){changeNickname = true;} else {changeNickname = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('SEND_MESSAGES')){sendMessages = true;} else {sendMessages = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')){manageMessages = true;} else {manageMessages = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('CONNECT')){Connect = true;} else {Connect = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('SPEAK')){Speak = true;} else {Speak = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('MUTE_MEMBERS')){muteMembers = true;} else {muteMembers = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('DEAFEN_MEMBERS')){defeanMembers = true;} else {defeanMembers = false;}
        if(role.hasPermission('MOVE_MEMBERS')){moveMembers = true;} else {moveMembers = false;}

        /*function changeRole(value = true) {
            role.edit({

            })
        }*/

        if(args[1])
        {
            switch(switchCase)
            {
                case 'administrator':
                    permAdministrator = !permAdministrator;
                    if(permAdministrator)
                    {
                        role.edit({
                            permissions: {
                                granted: ['ADMINISTRATOR']
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        role.edit({
                            permissions: {
                                denied: ['ADMINISTRATOR']
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    message.channel.send(`Administrator is now set to **${permAdministrator.valueOf()}**`);
                    break;
            }
        }

        let embed = new RichEmbed()
        .setColor(redlight)
        .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} editing **${role.name}**`, message.guild.iconURL)
        if(permAdministrator){embed.addField("**Administrator**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Administrator**", ":x:", true)}
        if(viewAudit){embed.addField("**View Audit Log**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**View Audit Log**", ":x:", true)}
        if(manageServer){embed.addField("**Manage Server**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Manage Server**", ":x:", true)}
        if(manageRoles){embed.addField("**Manage Roles**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Manage Roles**", ":x:", true)}
        if(manageChannels){embed.addField("**Manage Channels**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Manage Channels**", ":x:", true)}
        if(kickMembers){embed.addField("**Kick Members**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Kick Members**", ":x:", true)}
        if(banMembers){embed.addField("**Ban Members**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Ban Members**", ":x:", true)}
        if(changeNickname){embed.addField("**Change Nickname**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Change Nickname**", ":x:", true)}
        if(sendMessages){embed.addField("**Send Messages**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Send Messages**", ":x:", true)}
        if(manageMessages){embed.addField("**Manage Messages**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Manage Messages**", ":x:", true)}
        if(Connect){embed.addField("**Connect**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Connect**", ":x:", true)}
        if(Speak){embed.addField("**Speak**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Speak**", ":x:", true)}
        if(muteMembers){embed.addField("**Mute Members**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Mute Members**", ":x:", true)}
        if(defeanMembers){embed.addField("**Defean Members**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Defean Members**", ":x:", true)}
        if(moveMembers){embed.addField("**Move Members**", ":white_check_mark:", true)} else {embed.addField("**Move Members**", ":x:", true)}
        embed.setFooter("@Chateau | ");
        embed.setTimestamp();
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add array of permission, then check if role has this perm, then `remove`, else `add`.

> My permissions array not include all permissions, so you need to add somethink.

```js
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const { redlight } = require("../../colours.json")
const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const allPerm = [
        'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE',
        'KICK_MEMBERS',
        'BAN_MEMBERS',
        'ADMINISTRATOR',
        'MANAGE_CHANNELS',
        'MANAGE_GUILD',
        'ADD_REACTIONS',
        'READ_MESSAGES',
        'SEND_MESSAGES',
        'SEND_TTS_MESSAGES',
        'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
        'EMBED_LINKS',
        'ATTACH_FILES',
        'READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY',
        'MENTION_EVERYONE',
        'EXTERNAL_EMOJIS',
        'CONNECT',
        'SPEAK',
        'MUTE_MEMBERS',
        'DEAFEN_MEMBERS',
        'MOVE_MEMBERS',
        'USE_VAD',
        'CHANGE_NICKNAME',
        'MANAGE_NICKNAMES',
        'MANAGE_ROLES_OR_PERMISSIONS',
        'MANAGE_WEBHOOKS',
        'MANAGE_EMOJIS',
    ];
    if (args.length < 2) return message.reply('PLS cpecific a role and permission');
    let targetRole = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[0]) || message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === args[0]);
    let targetPermission = args[1];
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(['MANAGE_ROLES'])) return message.channel.send('You dont have permission to perform this command!');
    if (!targetRole.editable) return message.reply('Cant edit this role');
    if (!targetRole) return message.channel.send(`**${args[0]}** is not a valid role, did you spell it correctly?`);
    if (!allPerm.includes(targetPermission)) return message.channel.send(`Not valid permission, please use 1 of :\n ${allPerm.join('\n')}`);
    const currectPermmission = new Discord.Permissions(targetRole.permissions);
    let newTargetRolePermissions = currectPermmission.has(targetPermission) ? currectPermmission.remove(targetPermission) : currectPermmission.add(targetPermission);
    console.log(newTargetRolePermissions.toArray());
    targetRole
        .setPermissions(newTargetRolePermissions.toArray())
        .then(newRolePerm => {
            let embed = new RichEmbed();
            embed.setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} editing **${targetRole.name}**`, message.guild.iconURL);
            let arrayPerm = newRolePerm.permissions.toArray();
            allPerm.forEach(perm => {
                let fieldvalue = arrayPerm.includes(perm) ? ':white_check_mark:' : ':x:';
                embed.addField(perm, fieldvalue, true);
            });
            embed.setFooter('@Chateau | ');
            embed.setTimestamp();
            message.channel.send(embed);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            message.reply('Failed update a perm');
        });
```

[image: Now its fine]

Comment: I tried this and i got this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: Invalid permission string or number

Comment: It works, however when i'm setting one permission, all the other resets, and i'm not able to set a permissions to false if i don't activate a new one. Because then every permission other then the one i chose sets to false.

Comment: So, if if role has permission `KICK_MEMBERS,MANAGE_EMOJIS, ..... ` and you use commad to add `MANAGE_WEBHOOKS` its remove all role permissions and add only `MANAGE_WEBHOOKS` ? @Andresen

Comment: That is exactly whats happening

Comment: @Andresen, ooops, sorry i forgot to change varible in `set permissions`, now its gonna work fine : )

Comment: I'm still not able to disable the permission when trying to edit it after the first time.

Comment: @Andresen, now it\`s must work fine, i forgot thats some method now avalible in discord v11